# How to make HTML5 Canvas "Press/Click to play" start screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, event-handling, html5-canvas, splash-screen

I've finished the basic mechanic of a game and also done with the end screen. Now I plan to have a png made with Photoshop where the title and instructions are. And when I click/press enter I should be able to start the game like normal.

Been searching for quite sometimes but most of the answer seems to aim towards framework or complex menu.

My program also starts at this point

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    canvas1 = document.getElementById("gameCanvas1");
    canvasContext1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

    canvas2 = document.getElementById("gameCanvas2");
    canvasContext2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a game state manager to hold the current game state function then just listen to the mouse and key events during the splash screen state. The game state just holds the function you need to call once per frame to run the game or slash screen or end game screen.

```
function splashIO (event) {  // function to start the game when IO is correct
    // check for the correct events
    if(event.type === "click" || (event.type === "keydown" && event.code === "Enter")){
         // remove events
         canvas.removeEventListener("click",splashIO);
         canvas.removeEventListener("keydown",splashIO);
         gameStates.current = gameStates.startGame;
    }
}

// holds the game state and game state functions
const gameStates = {
     current : undefined,
     splash () {  // display splash ===================================
         // display splash and wait for new state
     },
     setupSplash () { // setup splash screen ==========================
         canvas.addEventListener("click", splashIO);
         canvas.addEventListener("keydown", splashIO);
         gameStates.current = gameStates.splash();
         gameStates.current(); // call the first frame
     },
     startGame () { // setup game =====================================
         gameStates.current = gameStates.game(); //set up state function
         gameStates.current();  // call the first frame
     },
     game () {  // plays the main game  ===============================
          // play game
     }
}

// main animation loop
function mainLoop () {
    gameStates.current(); // run current game state
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

gameStates.current = gameStates.setupSplash; // set current state to splash screen

// wait for page to load then start the animation
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop); // start the animation
}
```